# Cannot launch WAR, nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, rmi

I am in a project which uses the following relevant technologies:

- Maven
- Spring
- Java EE
- Java RMI

In my project, I have an initialization class, which I call the `ìnitService`. This service is responsible for launching the main structures that the program will later on use. If it fails, the program fails.

In this `initService` I am trying to set up an RMI server and a client. So far, this is only the equivalent of an "helloWorld". To achieve this purpose I have an interface and an implementation class:

```
public interface ICommunicator extends Remote{
    public boolean askNewVM() throws RemoteException;
    public boolean commitingSuicide() throws RemoteException;
}

public class RMICommunicator extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ICommunicator{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public RMICommunicator() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean askNewVM()  throws RemoteException{
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean commitingSuicide()  throws RemoteException{
        return false;
    }

}
```

So far so good. Then I try to compile and generate the `war` file using the `mvn install` command, which runs without problems.

The problems arise however when I deploy the generated `war` file into my server and try to launch it with Jetty 8.0. When I do that, the server is unable to launch due to the following error:

```
[ERROR][context.ContextLoader]: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jnd/thesis/service/loadBalancer/RMICommunicator
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jnd/thesis/service/loadBalancer/RMICommunicator
    at net.jnd.thesis.service.loadBalancer.VMManager.<init>(VMManager.java:83)
    at net.jnd.thesis.service.loadBalancer.VMManager.getInstance(VMManager.java:104)
    at net.jnd.thesis.service.loadBalancer.LoadBalancerService.start(LoadBalancerService.java:50)
    at net.jnd.thesis.service.InitializationService.start(InitializationService.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:132)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.jnd.thesis.service.loadBalancer.RMICommunicator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
    ... 64 more
```

I have researched this forum for similar problems, but without success. However, I did find this article on the problem:

- http://javarevisited.blogspot.pt/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

And by reading it, I believe (though I might be wrong), that my problem is the one described in step 12:

> 12) Java program can also
>   throw java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError during linking which occurs
>   during class loading in Java. One of the example of this scenario is
>   just delete the User class from our static initializer failure example
>   after compilation and they try to run the program. This time you will
>   get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError directly without 
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError and message for
>   NoClassDefFoundError is also just printing name of class as
>   testing/User i.e. User class from testing package. Watch out for this
>   carefully as here root cause is absent of User.class file.
>
> Read more:
>   http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html#ixzz2z8cNlxZ9

I do not believe I have any jars missing, so I think this is a guess just as good as any other.How do I fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an access problem. Turns out that the `security.policy` file for RMI was not being read correctly (was not being found at all) and so instead of getting a FileNotFoundException, I was somehow getting a ClassNotDefException.

Permissions man ... they're hell.

Answer (score 0):

First rename your *.war to *.zip and have a look if the compiled class exists.

Else, try a maven > update in your IDE, and make sure maven dependencies are added to the classpath. I sometime get these NoClassDev errors and after update and classpath check everything works fine again.